# Why does my game load another scene when i click? UNITY 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

This game is a pop-the-lock-style minigame. Every time I click in the point prefab the game loads another scene, but it is only supposed to do that when I click outside of the pointPrefab and after it goes past the pointPrefab without clicking.

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class DestroyPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool triggered = false;

    bool canClick = false;
    Collider2D collidedObject;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!triggered && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("Game over");
            SceneManager.LoadScene("FishingSpot");
        }
        else if (triggered && collidedObject != null && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            canClick = false;
            Debug.Log("Point Destroyed");
            Destroy(collidedObject.gameObject);
            collidedObject = null;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Entered");
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Point"))
        {
            canClick = true; 
            triggered = true;
            collidedObject = other;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("exited");
        if (canClick = true && other.gameObject.CompareTag("Point"))
        {
            collidedObject = null;
            Debug.Log("Game Over exit");
            SceneManager.LoadScene("FishingSpot");
        }
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Point"))
        {
            canClick = false;
            triggered = false;
            collidedObject = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting to destroy the pointPrefab after clicking instead of the other scene being loaded.

Comment: You might want to change `Update` to `FixedUpdate` since it's recommended when using physics and collision stuff.

Other than that, have you tried debugging the values in the update loop to see their actual values? When is the `LoadScene` called? You can add a breakpoint and let it trigger, that would help you see what's going wrong.

Comment: @Sead be careful with this, `Input.GetKeyDown()` **will not** work propelry inside of `FixedUpdate`...

Comment: This doesnt seem to handle "clicking" more location of object being or not being triggered.

Comment: @Sead He is not doing any physics or collision stuff inside `Update()` and he is also checking for `Input` there so that is a no no to use `FixedUpdate()` anyway.

Comment: Thanks, Jay and Sujoy. Yeah, I see, my Unity is a bit rusty, but I'm glad you two were here to correct me! I'll leave the comment as is for the context's sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```csharp
> if (canClick = true && other.gameObject.CompareTag("Point"))
> ...
> ```

One big issue I can observe is in your `if` condition of `OnTriggerExit2D()` method you're using assignment operator (=) instead of comparison (==). This will always set `canClick` to `true` and whenever you go outside of your trigger tagged `Point` it will load `FishingSpot` scene.

Instead change this to..

```csharp
if (canClick && other.gameObject.CompareTag("Point"))
```